# Does two cucumber steps in a scenario which belongs to the same step class trigger two separate constructors to execute the step

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

***Scenario:***

## (And I do this) Step1

## (And I do that) Step2

```
public class CucumberStep{
 private Object object; 
 public CucumberStep(){
    object = new Object();
  }

public void step1_stepDef(){
}

public void step2_stepDef(){
}

}
```

For the scenario described above, when it is running will Step1 and Step2 have its own version of the object which is constructed in the CucumberStep class.

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be only one instance of CucumberStep. You can pass info this way between steps. I'd also recommend using dependency injection if the real "object = new Object()" part allows it.